# Login with twitter javascript example code (Twitter API)

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to write javascript code for **login with twitter** but I can't find any example code. Can anyone help to send me **example code** of login with twitter? I have made too many research with **twitter developer community** or **developer blog** but I could not found anything. So please suggest me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is sample code for this (using Passport.js) on [Glitch](https://glitch.com/%7Etwitter-passport-example).

Comment: Hi Andy,

We can not do directly JavaScript code without using any JS library.

Comment: You could always look at a library like passport.js, twit or twitter-lite to see how they do it, if you want the raw JS code.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/log-in-with-twitter

(I've never done this, just googled)

Comment: Hi Samuel,

I have read this article but here is not any example.